# Draw an image out of a control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a control. It's a text box. I want to draw an image at the left of the control. The image should be painted outside the control. I could paint it one but inside.

Here is the code:

```
  private static Image requiredIcon = Resources.Icon_required;
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnPaint(e);
     if (base.Enabled && string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Text))
     {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(requiredIcon, 0, 0);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get a parent and use it for painting.

```
  protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnParentChanged(e);
     base.Parent.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Parent_Paint);
  }

  private void Parent_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    if (base.Enabled && string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Text))
    {
       e.Graphics.DrawImage(requiredIcon, 0, 0);
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's what I said in my answer ;)

Comment: Almost the same. But I can't override parent's methods. I know nothing about them

Answer (score 2):

Create a user control composed of a TextBox and a PictureBox. Then in the OnPaint event of your user control you will be able to draw outside the textbox (in the PictureBox control).

Here's a picture of what the UserControl could look like. It contains a PictureBox and a TextBox.

[image]

If you just want to draw an icon you just have to assigned it to the PictureBox. So the OnPaint may not be necessary in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of drawing the image, you could create an appropriate control, e.g. `PictureBox`, with it's `Image` property set to the appropriate image resource.

It may be easier to do this at design time rather than run time. If the image should not be shown intitially, set it's `Visible` property to false at design time and set it to true at run time when the image should be shown.

Comment: exactly what I was going to suggest :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overloading the `TextBox.OnPaint` method, you have to overload the Form's (or whatever is the parent component of the TextBox) `OnPaint` method, and paint the Image at the left hand side of the `TextBox`. You can't have the `TextBox` draw to an area outside its own bounds.